# elmah does not throw error page after implementing catch block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I have got action method which gets the result from GetTaskDetails method.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {           
            Tasks task = this._projectService.GetTaskDetails(id);

            return View(task);
        }

        public Tasks GetTaskDetails(int taskId)
        {
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            Tasks task = null;

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("usp_TaskGetByTaskId", conn);
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskId", taskId);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        if (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            task = new Tasks()
                            {
                                UniqueId = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["UniqueId"]),
                                ProjectId = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["ProjectId"]),
                                Sequence = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["Sequence"]),
                                Description = rdr["Description"].ToString(),
                                StaffId = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["StaffId"]),
                                StatusId = Convert.ToInt16(rdr["StatusId"]),
                                HeldBy = rdr["HeldBy"].ToString(),
                                Progress = rdr["Progress"].ToString()
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }               
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            return task;
        }
```

If there is no catch block, elmah is logging the error in the database and redirecting to error page which is what i want. But the code has not got the catch block.
But if there is a catch block added to GetTaskDetails method as below

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);                 
}
```

The error is logged to the database and the control returns to the action method without throwing error page.
Is there a way to have the catch block to log to database and then throw an error page rather than redirecting to controller? I am not sure What I am thinking is the right approach or should it need to handle the exception again in the controller action method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can throw the exception after logging to ELMAH, which will cause the error page to show:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);                 
    throw;
}
```

I don't see any benefit in doing so, since that solution will work exactly like when not having the catch block. Maybe you could explain more about what you are trying to achieve here? I don't really see the problem in your question.

Comment: Try block without catch didn't seem convincing to me. Is it really a best practice? can you please advice

Comment: The whole idea with ELMAH is to log uncaught exceptions. If you want to handle a known error in your code, you should handle that using try-catch and redirecting to an error page or similar in your catch. If handling a known error, I wouldn't recommend to log to ELMAH, since that should be a list of errors to fix really.